# UpdatePanel is causing full (rather than partial) PostBack

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, partial-postback

I used an `UpdatePanel` to prevent the whole page from reloading when I click on the button.

I did my code well, and I tried to prevent the page from loading when I click the button, but the page reloads again regardless. How can I solve this problem?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="dd" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="PostPanel" Style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div class="modalPopup">
        <div class="PopupBody">
            <p class="ads-text">
                Go </p>
        </div>
        <div class="Controls">
            <div class="post">
                <asp:Button Text="OK" runat="server" ID="btnOkay" ValidationGroup="AddUserpopup"
                    OnClick="btnOkay_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="btnOkay" EventName="CLick"/>
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: The `AsyncPostBackTrigger` is redundant since you are not using `UpdateMode=Conditional`. By default all controls in the `UpdatePanel` post back asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You need to set the UpdateMode and ChildrenAsTriggers properties. Also, your event name had incorrect capitalization.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="dd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="PostPanel" Style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div class="modalPopup">
        <div class="PopupBody">
            <p class="ads-text">
                Go </p>
        </div>
        <div class="Controls">
            <div class="post">
                <asp:Button Text="OK" runat="server" ID="btnOkay" ValidationGroup="AddUserpopup"
                    OnClick="btnOkay_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="btnOkay" EventName="Click"/>
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Just a warning. jquery is incompatible with the updatepanel, calling any jquery function causes the UP to do a full postback. I ran into this, and after many hours of fiddling, I traced the problem down to jQuery.

Comment: @MC9000 Then you had a bug, because my company uses jQuery with UpdatePanel all the time. Not that I like it, but it does function.

Comment: Not a bug, but a feature. LOL!  I have many sites that use both, but, every single time a new javascript framework is introduced, it breaks all the hacks required to get it to work.  For simple stuff, it works fine, then add auto-sizing tables, context sensitive dropdowns, etc, then it's just simpler to use jquery ajax.
But they are incompatible out of the box. This much any dev will agree on.